# Generating set of the permutation group

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, permutations, finite-fields

It is known that the set of all transpositions generate the symmetric group.

In the book "Finite Fields" by Lidl and Neiderreiter, in the context of permutation polynomials, they discuss in one of the proofs that it is sufficient to consider the transpositions of the form $(0a)$, where $a\in \mathbb{F}_q^*$ and $0$ is the zero of the field $\mathbb{F}$ for generating the symmetric group $S_q$, because $(bc)=(0b)(0c)(0b)$.

Now, $0$ is usually not considered a part of the set of symbols on which the symmetric group is defined. What do they mean by the 'transposition'$(0a)$ here and how is the multiplication operation defined? I think the multiplication of two 'transpositions' here corresponds to composition of two polynomials associated to the 'transpositions' in the finite field. Any hints Thanks beforehand.

Comment: $0$ is an element of the finite field, and here they are considering permutations of the finite field.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown I know, but how does the multiplication of two 'transpositions take place?

Comment: You can consider the permutations of any set $A$. It  is just convenient to pick $S=\{1,2,\ldots,n\}$ when defining $S_n$, but you can take any set of cardinality $n$. Note that $a,b,c\in\Bbb F_q$ are not  $\in\{1,2,\ldots,n\}$ either. -- The multiplication of transpositions is the multiplicaton in the symmetric group, i.e., composition of maps

Comment: @vidyarthi Transpositions are permutations. "Multiplication" of permutations is composition.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen so, does that mean that a generating set of the symmetric group on finite field elements is transpositions of the form $(0a)$, $a\in\mathbb{F}_q^*$

Comment: @vidyarthi Yes, those transpositions do generate the permutations of $\Bbb F_q$.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown applying the same reasoning, then does the set of permutations of the form $(1a), a\in\{1,2,\ldots,n\}$ generate the symmetric group $S_n$?

Comment: Yes. @vidyarthi

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown oh! I actually thought that the set of all transpositions is a $\textbf{minimal}$ generating set of the symmetric group! So this shows it is not so

Answer (score 1):

The fact is the normal transposition defined for symmetric groups, except that the symmetric group is defined for the elements of the finite field. The multiplication of transpositions is the normal composition of permutations. The confusion arose because of the faulty thinking that the set of all transpoitions is a minimal generating set of the symmetric group, which is not so.